# How to fix a leak in an inaccessible bathtub fixture?

Tags: leak, bathtub

Back to my previous homeowners doing weird things.

When we got the home inspection, one of the things the inspector noted that for the large jetted tub in the master bath, there was no access panel or other way to get at the workings of the tub if the motor happened to go out or similar.

Fast forward 7 years, and now the waterfall spigot has developed a leak as shown below:
[image]

Is there a way to fix this externally, or do I need to hire someone to come in and get access and fix it? (I could saw out a bunch of drywall, but my drywalling skills are mediocre at best).

Answer (score 2):

The hot and cold control valves are generally serviceable from above. I would guess (can't say for sure because I don't recognize the brand and model) that you could pry up the circular cover on top of the knob(s) to access a screw that would allow knob removal.

From there, you should be able to disassemble the valve assembly by taking apart the packing assembly, unscrewing the stem, and replacing the worn out washer(s) that are causing the leak (make sure you shut off the water supply first).

This is by no means a sure thing, some *roman tub* (that term may help you with finding parts) faucets have other means of securing the knobs (like a set screw on the side), and some have proprietary valve designs that do not work like traditional faucet valves. There are myriad brands and styles both foreign and domestic. If you can get the knobs off, you could at least take them to a reputable plumbing supply shop to try to identify your unit and get more information to help you repair it..